# Jquery stop event for context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseevent

I'm making a context menu, but there a problem for my context menu, when I right click I wish the context menu stop on the position. I have tried using `.stop()` but it doesn't work.

This is the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uw6h8LL8/)

**JQUERY**

```
$(".menu").hide();
$(document).on("contextmenu", ".element", function (e) {

    $(".menu").fadeIn();
    return false;
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    $(".menu").fadeOut(300);
});



$(document).bind('mousemove', function(e){
    $('.menu').css({
       left:  e.pageX + 20,
       top:   e.pageY
    });
    $(".menu").stop();
});
```

Comment: wouldn't it just be easier to use the `contextmenu` event to set position of the menu and get rid of the mousemove? Otherwise you need to unbind mousemove when menu is shown, and bind it back again after

Comment: @charlietfl did u hv example to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach where you check if the menu is visible and don't move it if it is.

```
    var $menu = $(".menu").hide();
    $(document).on("contextmenu", ".element", function (e) {
        $menu.fadeIn();
        return false;
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        $menu.fadeOut(300);
    });

    $(document).bind('mousemove', function (e) {
        if ($menu.is(':visible')) {
            return;
        }
        $menu.css({
            left: e.pageX + 20,
            top: e.pageY
        });

    });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uw6h8LL8/2/)**</kbd>

Alternatively you can use the `contextmenu` event to set menu position without using mousemove.

```
   $(document).on("contextmenu", ".element", function (e) {
        $menu.css({
            left: e.pageX + 20,
            top: e.pageY
        }).fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/uw6h8LL8/3/)**</kbd>